# How to get a list of recent contacts in Skype for Business

Tags: microsoft-outlook, skype, skype-for-business

The company I work for recently switched Microsoft Office Communicator to Skype for Business and there is one function I really miss.

In the Office communicator there was a list of recent contacts. Everytime there was a chat or call, the other user was added to this list and it was sorted by when the last interaction happened.

Skype for Business does not seem to have this capability. I can manually add people to my contacts, but they are sorted in some static way (by groups I define and alphabetically). There is also the "conversations" view, showing the last conversations, but the contacts in my team appear multiple times, because I talk to them more frequently.

Is there any way to have a list of recent contacts or at least a possibility to sort my contacts by when the last interaction happened?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is not feature yet:

https://www.skypefeedback.com/forums/299913-generally-available/suggestions/9606435-add-group-for-recent-contacts-history

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't the history (clock icon) tab offer that information?

Skype for Business 2015 History tab - most recent activity:

[image: Skype for Business 2015 History tab - most recent activity]

Comment: It does not. Contacts appear there multiple time, so it is all cluttered with the colleagues in my own team. This is the "conversations" view I mentioned in the question.

Comment: This is the history tab. So, it will show the recent / previous conversations  (including telephony). This list, for me, is more than sufficient for who recently contacted me...